# Gerrit change-merged on specific repo

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm investigating into using hooks with Gerrit, and am curious about their execution.

Specifically, when you create a hook, such as change-merged, is that run for all reviews on Gerrit, or can it be run only per specific git repo. We have many repos and use Gerrit for reviewing, and for a specific repo I'd like to create a script that triggers when it is changed.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Gerrit's hook configuration is global, i.e. applies equally to all Gerrit-managed repositories, but since Gerrit supplies the repository name to the hook you can have a simple condition inside the hook to choose whether to actually do anything.